# R (dplyr): lag values within a group

Tags: r, lag, dplyr

I want to calculate the comparison between a start value and the lagged end value. This comparison should only take place within a certain group (of the start value). If there is no previous "end" value within this group, the comparison value should be NA.

This is my data:

```
library(dplyr)
dfData <- data.frame(
                    start = c(100, 239, 392, 700, 770), 
                    end = c(200, 390, 550, 760, 900),
                    group= c(1,1,2,3,3))
```

I first tried this code using dplyr,

```
 dfData <- mutate(dfData, comparison = start - lag(end))
```

which resulted in the following data frame:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>start</th><th>end</th><th>group</th><th>comparison</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>100</td><td>200</td><td>1</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>239</td><td>390</td><td>1</td><td>39</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>392</td><td>550</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>700</td><td>760</td><td>3</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>770</td><td>900</td><td>3</td><td>10</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This gives me the standard lag along all values (not depending on my group status). How do I tell R to perform the lag operation only within my group and not between the groups? I don't want the lag to be calculated when jumping from one group to the other.

This is my intended Result:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>start</th><th>end</th><th>group</th><th>comparison</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>100</td><td>200</td><td>1</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>239</td><td>390</td><td>1</td><td>39</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>392</td><td>550</td><td>2</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>700</td><td>760</td><td>3</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>770</td><td>900</td><td>3</td><td>10</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: You need to group it by group first, i.e. `dfData %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(comparison = start - lag(end))`

Comment: worked superb! Thank you!